# Installing a faster Pentium CPU than the one listed in the motherboard manual

Tags: cpu, motherboard, intel-pentium

According to my old Intel D810EMO motherboard manual, the faster processor supported is **Pentium III 800EB**. However, there are [Pentium III processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Pentium_III_microprocessors#%22Coppermine%22_(180_nm)) with Socket 370 up to 1.13Ghz, so the question is **can I safely install one of these faster CPUs** in this motherboard? Unfortunately, Intel has removed all firmware downloads last year, so there's no way of knowing if a FW update to support faster processors was ever released, and I'm not sure if it's needed.

Comment: It would be an experiment on your part if it works or not. No way to know beforehand.

Comment: That is such bullcrap they pulled downloads for old desktop boards. Yeah, like it takes up so much server space.

Comment: Here is a bios update for the D810E2CB ( do not apply it) it includes the updated microcode for the P111 1.1ghz, now if someone were a bios expert they could build a bios update to push this processor microcode to your bios, >>>https://www.userdrivers.com/BIOS/Intel-D810E2CB-Motherboard-BIOS-P10-Update/

Comment: You might contact them and inquire about a bios update for your specific board info@userdrivers.com

Comment: Found some here, but do we trust them they are correct for your board>>>>https://rebyte.me/en/intel/135110/